# Videos stop, but audio keeps going until I move my mouse

Tags: mouse, audio, video-playback

Like said in the title. Whenever I am on DataCamp watching a video or just YouTube. After I let the mouse alone, the video stops and the audio keeps going until I move my muse and the video instantly just catches up with the audio. Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: I have an Acer Aspire 13 running Elementary OS 5.0.

Comment: edit your own post and add all the information there, gl

Comment: See https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/121

Comment: Same problem here. Intel HD Graphics (i7-6500U) running eOS Juno with latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/elementary/os/issues/121#issuecomment-432652260

Assuming Intel  graphics

Modify (or create) `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` with the following:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel Graphics"
    Driver "intel"
    Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
    Option "TearFree" "true"
    Option "DRI" "3"
EndSection
```